# Is a question that can be answered by simply watching/reading welcome here?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted a [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39724/why-was-the-movie-so-vastly-different-from-the-book) asking about the Percy Jackson movie. I initially had a secondary, minor question asking if the second movie was just as different from it's book. In a comment, Keen suggests making that into an individual question asking "does the second movie depend upon the story from the first movie, or the first book?" However, this can be answered simply by watching the movie and reading the book. Are these types of questions right for the site?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Should we close questions for being “too trivial”?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3070/13941), [I haven't read the book/watched the movie/… May I ask a question about it?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2372/13941), and/or [Should we burninate General Reference?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2400/13941). Do we need a new topic to continue the discussion, if the discussion is worth continuing at all?